# how to get the result of adding the values of two text box inside angualrjs controller

Tags: angularjs, addition, angular-ngmodel

I want to get the result of adding to two text box value inside a controller

```
  <div ng-app="">

        <p>First Number:
            <input type="text" ng-model="a" />
        </p>
        <p>Second Number:
            <input type="text" ng-model="b" />
        </p>
      <p>Second Number:
            <input type="text" ng-model="a+b" />
        </p>
</div>
```

i will get the value addded but if i use the expression in the model how to get in the controller

and i am getting the error has ngModelSet is not a function

As soon as the user enters the value in two textbox the result of adding two text box should be shown in the 3rd textbox and there is a submit button which give the value to controller how to do it please help

Answer (score 0):

use `ng-change="my_operation()"`.

Dont put the js instructions inside the 'ng-change' because the $scope may be a children of the controller's and you will get display problem.

Write the function `my_operation` like this:

```
$scope.my_operation = function() {
  $scope.c = $scope.a + $scope.b;
};
```

`<input type="text" ng-model="my_operation()" value="{{ c }}" />`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify variables in the `ng-model` directive, not expressions.

So, this is invalid: `<input type="text" ng-model="a+b" />`

Rather, do `c = a + b` somewhere and set `ng-model="c"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <p>First Number:
        <input type="text" ng-model="a" />
    </p>
    <p>Second Number:
        <input type="text" ng-model="b" />
    </p>
    <p>Answer:{{a+b}}</p>

    <div class="btn" ng-click=submitFnc(a+b) ng-disabled="!a||!b">Submit</div>
```

in the function

```
$scope.submitFnc = function(ans) {
  $scope.ans = ans;
};
```

the previous answer by Pierre Emmanuel Lallemant is also Correct

but you requirement in the description is slight different try this one also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div ng-app="">
        <p>First Number:</p>
            <input type="text" ng-model="a" />
        <p>Second Number: </p>
            <input type="text" ng-model="b" />
        <p>Final:</p>
            <input type="text" value="{{ ans }}" />
            <p>{{ans}}</p>
         <button ng-click="finalResult()" class="btn-style">
</div>
```

**In Controller**

```
$scope.finalResult = function() {
  $scope.ans = $scope.a + $scope.b;
};
```

Comment: Why use `div` and not `a` or `button`? Doesn't make sense.